# Math Expression in RMarkdown and Markdown (RStudio)

Tags: html, rstudio, markdown, knitr, r-markdown

I was trying to create a technical note in R Markdown with Knit in RStudio. If I output an html file, it works well. However, if I output a Markdown (to be uploaded as a post in blog) file, some formulas cannot be shown correctly. Does anyone know why? Thanks in advance.

This is the .rmd file
[image]

This is the html output (works)
[image]

This is the .md file (some formula breaks)
[image]

Comment: Short answer: [use blogdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/) if you don't want to waste time on this kind of problems.

Comment: @YihuiXie Thanks Yihui. When I run blogdown::new_site(), I got an error saying "Error in invalidUTF8(x): could not find function "invalidUTF8". Any idea on this?

Comment: Have you [updated all your R packages?](https://yihui.name/en/2017/05/when-in-doubt-upgrade/) The current latest version of blogdown on CRAN is 0.5.

Comment: @YihuiXie Updating Blogdown alone solved the problem. Thanks again for help.

Comment: @YihuiXie Hi, Yihui I followed the tutorial at https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/other-themes.html and publish a post at https://wenbo5565.github.io/post/testingpage-rmd/ . You can see I still have the same issue displaying some formulas. I guess I missed some settings in Blogdown? Can you please give me a hand? Thank you.

Comment: @YihuiXie No need to look into the question. I later found I have to set it as .Rmd file not the default .md file. Sorry to interrupt.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks a lot for letting me know! (I almost started investigating your problem! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164212/discussion-between-wenbo-and-yihui-xie).